# Django permalink from view with optional parameters

Tags: python, django, url, permalinks

I'm trying to use one view to resolve two url patterns, by using optional parameters in the view definition.
I'm following recomendations from [this post](http://lethain.com/using-optional-parameters-in-django-urls/) and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352834/optional-get-parameters-in-django).

Here's my code for the url patterns **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'my_view', name='main_url'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<optional>[\w-]*)/$', 'my_view', name='optional_url'),
)
```

And the definition of the view:

```
def my_view(request, slug, optional=None):
```

Everything works fine, as far as displaying the templates according to the url patterns.
However, when I try to display links using model permalinks, it breaks. I'm following the way of getting a model absolute url as explained in django docs.

Here's the code of my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('main_url', [self.slug])
```

The problem is that get_absolute_url returns an url with two arguments. So I'm getting something like this domain.com/slug// instead of this domain.com/slug/

How can I get the absolute url without the second argument?
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You return a list in your `get_absolute_url` function, that's why you get two parameters.
You could just do like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/%s/" % self.slug
```

Comment: Tanks Ole. That would work for sure, but I wouldn't be using the permalink function. Isn't here a way od making it work using permalink()?

Comment: That one should be just as good as a permalink, and it's what I personally use to get the urls for my own Django applications. To be honest i'm not quite sure what that `@models.permalink` decorator is used for, but the above function should be all you need, a permalink is really just what it says "a permanent link"