# Why does this URLConf/reverse() combination, with duplicate named url entries, work? What is the correct way to do this?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

- URLConf:

  ```
  url(r'^body/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'body_part_detail', name='body-part-detail'),
  url(r'^body/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', 'body_part_detail', name='body-part-detail'),
  ```
- `get_absolute_url()` implementation:

  ```
  def get_absolute_url(self):
      kwargs = {
          'id' : self.id,
          'slug' : slugify(self.name)
      }

      return reverse('body-part-detail', kwargs=kwargs)
  ```

Now, I've got two `url`s where `name=body-part-detail` (which may be wrong?). Nevertheless, `reverse` succeeds in the sense that it uses the second `url` and returns the desired URL with the slug component. Why does this work? Am I just "lucky" in this case (quotes because programs shouldn't be lucky!)?

Finally, there are several places on SO and the Web where people give examples of URLConfs with `url`s that share `name` keyword arg. For example, Visgean Skeloru's answer here: [Optional get parameters in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352834/optional-get-parameters-in-django). Is this wrong/bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `reverse` function is identifying that you have the kwargs `id` and `slug` along with a pattern name `body-part-detail`, and returning the only url that corresponds to those kwargs and that name. You're not lucky, that's what `reverse` is designed to do.

You may be able to use the same name for numerous patterns but I don't think that's how it was designed to work (I can see a very old bug ticket that suggested [implementing a check](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4824) to ensure there aren't any duplicates). I suspect that your app will be easier to maintain if you use a unique name for each pattern. Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) for me more info.

Comment: Aidan—thanks very much for the ticket link at code.djangoproject.com. Always very good to read through the thinking when something like this is "wontfix".

Answer (score 3):

In your `reverse()` call you're passing two arguments. So Django discovers that it can't match it to the first URL because, although the name is correct, that URL only has one URL parameter. So Django necessarily matches it to the second URL.

Optional URL patterns are okay but it's best to give each URL a unique name and use that to reverse URLs. That removes any ambiguity when resolving URLs and it also makes the code easier to follow for yourself and other developers.

Comment: Ha, you beat me to it! +1 for affirming my (shaky) understanding of the subject!