# Django url pattern with 2 parameters misinterprets the second parameter

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352834/optional-get-parameters-in-django/1352841#1352841) pattern to pass 2 parameters in an URL, where the second parameter is optional. This is my code:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^topic/(?P<topic>.*)/(?P<page>.*)/$', activities_list, 
    url(r'^topic/(?P<topic>.*)/$', activities_list, name='activities'),name='activities_page'),
)
```

This works, except when the second parameter is `1`. In that case, *topic* is `topic/1` and and *page* is `None`. It works for any other number as a second parameter.

Who can put me in the right direction to solve this bug?

**UPDATE, this is getting weird**

After trying several things, I discovered that this template tag makes the problem:

```
<img src="{{recommendation.user_picture_url}}" />
```

When I delete this tag, or even remove it from the **src** attribute and place it outside the image tag, the URL works. The variable contains a URL to a LinkedIn avatar on Linkedin's servers.

This is my view

```
def activities_list(request, topic, page=1):

    print topic
    print page
    ...
    return render_to_response(...
```

I don't understand why my view is getting the wrong parameters from the URL (as seen in the prints), while the hole response hasn't even been rendered yet.

**Update: Solved! (see below)**

Comment: I would recommend 2 things -  1. Change the order of the 2 URL patterns, 2. Narrow the regex match to something like `[\w_-]+` if you can..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found that when pictures in my test-database are missing, the template tag will give a `None` value in the image tag src attribute. This caused a request to the server to look for the image on URL */topic/1/None*. Somehow, this happened even before the response was send to the client, so that my view received new, wrong, parameters.

This tag in my template on page .../topic/1/ requests the image from .../topic/1/None, sending wrong parameters.

```
<img src="{{recommendation.user_picture_url}}" />
```

PS Thanks falsetru for the improvements in the regex

Answer (score 1):

Use non-greey qualifier (`.*?` or `.+?`):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^topic/(?P<topic>.+?)/$', activities_list, name='activities'),
    url(r'^topic/(?P<topic>.+?)/(?P<page>.+?)/$', activities_list, name='activities_page'),
)
```

For page number, `\d+` is more appropriate.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^topic/(?P<topic>.*?)/$', activities_list, name='activities'),
    url(r'^topic/(?P<topic>.*?)/(?P<page>\d+)/$', activities_list, name='activities_page'),
)
```

Instead of `(?P<topic>.*?)`, you can also use `(?P<topic>[^/]+)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. If I add the `?` in both parameters, _topic_ is `topic1/1/None`. This is only when the page parameter is 1, it does work with any other number. (I also tried copy pasting your entire code)

Comment: @jvannistelrooy, What about `r'^topic/(?P<topic>[^/]+)/$'` and `r'^topic/(?P<topic>[^/]+)/(?P<page>\d+)/$'`

Comment: It sure was helpful, but it did not solve my problem.