# How to pass an optional argument to url in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

I have an url pattern with one optional parameter:

```
# urls.py :
url(r'^(page/(?P<page>\w+))?$', MyIndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Pagination and everything else works well, until I create an url to a specific page in my template:

```
# templates/mysite.html
{% url 'index' 54 %}
```

Then I get an error:

```
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '(54,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'(page/(?P<page>\\w+))?$']
```

Without the parameter it works:

```
{% url 'index' %}
```

I also tried:

```
{% url 'index' page=54 %}
```

and got similar error.

Comment: Its a bit of creepy to use optional arguments. There might be issues related to tailing `/` of URL etc. I'd suggest you to not use it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create two URL patterns, one with a default parameter to 1 and the other with the `page` matching in the URL:

```
# urls.py :
url(r'^page$', MyIndexView.as_view(), {'page': 1}, name='index'),
url(r'^page/(?P<page>\w+)$', MyIndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

The third argument of [the `url` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.url) is `kwargs`, hence `kwargs['page']` will be 1 in the first case and defined by the URL in the second.

Comment: Even without this, it works well. The error appear only when I try to use `{% url ... %}`

Comment: Indeed... I have always used two patterns for this kind of case and it seems to be a convention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352834/optional-get-parameters-in-django 
I don't really see why it is not matching your URL for your pattern (maybe just a typo I don't see right now) but I leave my answer as a working alternative ;)

Comment: Well, adding second pattern haven't changed anything. It still works unitl I use `{% url ... %}`

Comment: @MaximeLorant you need to use a different name in the second url pattern