# Django - regex optional function parameters in URL

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I am starting off with Django now (already have quite a bit of Python knowledge, as well as with other languages). I am wondering whether it is possible to pass optional parameters through the url to a view (function that is called when a certain url is entered). What I have:

`url(regex=r'^bydate/year=(?P<year>[0-9]+)_month=(?P<month>[0-9]+)_day=(?P<day>[0-9]+)/$', view=views.question_by_date, name='question_by_date')`

So, in other words, if the end of the url looks like this, for example:

`...bydate/year=2001_month=11_day=2/`

then it calls the `question_by_date` function, whose signature looks as follows:

`question_by_date(request, **kwargs)`

So with the above url, `question_by_date` will be called as

`question_by_date(request, year=2001, month=11, day=2)`

But I also want the user to be able to type in the url specifying just the year, e.g.

`...bydate/year=2005/`

which will call

`question_by_date(request, year=2005)`

Or for that matter, any combination of year, month, day (like just the year and the month, or just the year and day even, etc.)

So, is this possible? I am not so experienced in regex, and I understand that you can have optional string matches (zero or more) in regex, which will match the above just fine in normal circumstances, but here we are also passing (optional) parameters to a function.

NOTE:

A very similar question to this has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352834/optional-get-parameters-in-django). I realize that I could make a different URL for each combination, but that would entail making 8 different URLs. Also, that question was asked 6 years ago. Hopefully some enhancement has been made in the meantime?

Comment: @ShangWang didn't read through the whole document, but what about if I want to enable the user to just enter the day? Or just the month? Wouldn't a named "parameter" in the URL itself make resolving that easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is `GET` parameters for this:

1. Define you url without any parameters:

   `url(r'^bydate/$', views.question_by_date, name='question-by-date')`
2. In your views, extract `GET` parameters:

`from datetime import date`

```
def question_by_date(request):
    year = request.GET.get('year', 2005)
    month = request.GET.get('month', 1)
    day = request.GET.get('day', 1)
    # use the parameters however you want afterwards
```

3. Call your url like:

   http://localhost:8000/bydate/?year=2016&month=1&day=1

Check [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#get-and-post) for more details about http `GET`.